# Deploy custom_resource_definition on k8s using API

Tags: kubernetes

How can I deploy a CRD on K8s cluster without using `kubectl create -f crd.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

kubectl is simply a client to the api, so you can do so with any API client, like client libraries for different languages. My choice would be **Go** as that's kubes native language so it'll always be up to date with latest version.

First create new CRD object in memory, and then use native client with something like

```
client.ApiextensionsV1beta1().CustomResourceDefinitions().Create(crd)
```